# Using XPath, how do I select only the links that have a particular child present under the links sibling element

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

How do I select only the middle install name using the criteria below?

---

Within a table I have multiple table rows. Inside of these table rows is a link (inside of a <td>) that contains the URL and name of a particular install which can easily be selected with:

```
//td[contains(@class, 'install-name')]/a/text()
```

Instead of selecting all of the install names, I only want to select the installs that are locked. Only the locked installs contain this element located inside of the links sibling element.

```
//div[@class="install-details"]/span/i[contains(@class, 'password-protected')]
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr class="install odd" role="row">
    <td class="install-name sorting_1" data-sort="demo"><a href="/installs/demo">demo</a>
        <div class="install-details">
        <span>

        </span> 
        <span class="php-version">

        </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="install even" role="row">
    <td class="install-name sorting_1" data-sort="adam">
        <a href="/installs/adam">adam</a>
        <div class="install-details">
            <span>
                <i class="install-status-icon password-protected fa fa-lock" title="Password Protected"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="php-version">

            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="install odd" role="row">
    <td class="install-name sorting_1" data-sort="amy">
        <a href="/installs/amy">amy</a>
        <div class="install-details">
                <span>

                </span>
                <span class="php-version">

                </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

How do I select only the middle install name using the criteria above?

Edit: Here is a CodePen to play with https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvEbba

Comment: What do you want exactly select? i.e `a`, `td`, or `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your second XPath as an additional predicate (expression in `[]`) to your first XPath as follows :

```
//td[contains(@class, 'install-name')]
    [div[@class="install-details"]/span/i[contains(@class, 'password-protected')]]
 /a/text()
```

**<kbd>[`xpath demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/k-ojA2OQd)</kbd>**

Notice the 2nd predicate which should limit the result to those `td` which contains 'password-protected' information.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks. I didn't know about predicates.

Answer (score 1):

How about traversing the HTML backwards.

```
//i[contains(@class, 'password-protected')]/parent::span/parent::div[@class='install-details']/preceding-sibling::a/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I ended up using the other because it seemed a bit more straight forward but I didn't know I could do this, good to know!